# Controll flutter pageview widgets or variables for one page only

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How to control specific widget to hide or to show in pageview. In PageView Widget in flutter for specific page only, how we can control over widget to be hidden or shown based on bool value. how we can utilize pageview controller to do this

Answer (score 0):

you can change the children in the widget tree depending on a boolean value.
Example: `child: condition ? WidgetWhenTrue : WidgetWhenFalse`

## UPDATE

The best way I found is, that you create your pages and page children dynamicly.
You could provide a `List<Widget>` which will represent the max. Content and then remove the widget you don't want to have.
Or you could add the widgets on the fly to the pages.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PageViewWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PageViewWidgetState createState() => _PageViewWidgetState();
}

class _PageViewWidgetState extends State<PageViewWidget> {
  PageController _pageController;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  List<Text> maxContent = [
    Text('text 1'),
    Text('text 2'),
    Text('text 3'),
    Text('text 4'),
    Text('text 5'),
    Text('text 6')
  ];

  bool condition = true;

  Container dynamicPageChildren({Color color, List<int> delPos}) {
    Container newPage;
    List<Widget> newContent = List.from(maxContent);
    // modify your Widget List
    print('length = ${maxContent.length} ');
    for (int i in delPos.reversed) {
      // use reversed or provide the last elemt to remove first if not,
      // your list will shrink and the element you want to remove last does not exist or is the wrong one
      print('delete at pos $i');
      newContent.removeAt(i);
    }
    // add it to the page
    newPage = Container(
        color: color,
        child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: newContent));
    return newPage;
  }

  List<Container> dynamicPages({List<Color> colorList}) {
    // you could also pass the index positions into this function
    // or call your logic to decide which index should not be displayed
    List<Container> newPageList = [];
    // modify your Widget List
    int i = 0;
    for (Color color in colorList) {
      // example with given indices
      // newPageList.add(dynamicPageChildren(color: color, delPos: [1, 3, 5]));

      newPageList.add(dynamicPageChildren(color: color, delPos: [i]));
      i = i + 1;
    }

    return newPageList;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: PageView(
            controller: _pageController,
            children: dynamicPages(
                colorList: [Colors.red, Colors.orange, Colors.yellow])),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your proposed solution @SeriForte ... let me explain it more ... suppose that we have 10 pages in pageview widget .... i need for example to hide widget x from page number 5... is there a way that i can  control that widget bu passing page number as index.... something like controller.page[5].WIDGET X..... or anything similar to that

Comment: @alfarqi I updated the code. As far as I know, the pagecontroller or widget in general don't let you remove/change their children. You could access some properties of widgets, such as color or children, but their inmutable and must be destroyed in order to reflect the changes. But I'm not sooo experienced so I might be wrong.